Fresh install nvim error opening astro file
Fresh system install.
SO: Sonoma 14.5
Nnvim: 0.10.0 with empty config (same error on both: with brew install and downloaded binary)
Have 4 astro projects and this only happen on 2 of them.
I've been looking for a clue 2 days, but nothing have come to my mind... any suggestions?
Many thanks! :)
Brew install:
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: Error executing lua: ...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: BufReadPost Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocommands
 for "*"..function <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin[20]..script /opt/homebrew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/astro.vim[163]..function <SNR>21_CollectPathsFromConfig, line 11: Vim(let):E474: Trailing comma: }   } }
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        ...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: in function <...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        ...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function <...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        ...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function <...rew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>

Binary downloaded:
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: Error executing lua: ...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: BufReadPost Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocommands
 for "*"..function <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin[20]..script /Users/juanjo/Downloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/astro.vim[163]..function <SNR>21_CollectPathsFromConfig, line 11: Vim(let):E474: Trailing comma: }   } }
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        ...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: in function <...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        ...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function <...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        ...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function <...wnloads/nvim-macos-arm64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>


Solved! The trailing comma error was in one of my files, at jsconfig.js
